# Generate a universal binary Xcode project to include two sets of pre-compiled libraries

Tags: xcode, cmake, build, shared-libraries

I am trying to build Blender as a universal binary. Blender has a lot of libraries that can be downloaded completely pre-compiled from their subversion servers. They have one set for x86 and one set for arm64. Blender docs instruct me to run `cmake . -B ../build_xcode/ -G "Xcode"` which generated a `Blender.xcodeproj` file and other build files. I noticed that cmake is only picking up the arm64 dependencies, however which might explain why my buils keep failing 90% of the way through. I can build both arm64 and x86_64 builds separately, but not combined. Is there a way to generate this Xcode project to contain both x86 and arm64 dependencies into the same project? I have selected "Standard Architectures" in my build settings so I can confirm it is indeed configured to build a universal binary.

I have checked other posts on this website and most are for PPC/Intel days or are not relevant to my specific issue.